# How to hide and show a router component on an onclick event in react js

Tags: reactjs, routes, toggle

I am trying to hide and show a router component on an onclick event in REACTJS.but didn't find the way i could do that.Help me with that.
here's my code-

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Route, Link, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import SignIn from './SignIn'

export default class Clicksigningin extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <Router>
             <div>
             <Link to={'/SignIn'}><button className='btn btn-danger'>Sign In</button></Link>
             <Switch>
                 <Route exact path = '/SignIn' component = {SignIn} />
             </Switch>
             </div>
            </Router>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better way to do this is get rid of router for this particular component.
Inside a single component (say SignIn) you can have a button which will toggle (show/hide) the signIn part.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Route, Link, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import SignIn from './SignIn'

export default class Clicksigningin extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={showSignInPage:false}
}

toggleSignIn(){
    this.setState({showSignInPage:!this.state.showSignInPage});
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {this.state.showSignInPage && <SignIn/>}
            <button className='btn btn-danger' onClick={()=>this.toggleSignIn()}>Sign In</button>

         </div>
        </Router>
    </div>
)
}
```

PS: Code I have not tested.

Comment: Router is necessary in reactjs for  hyperlinking.I am hyperlinking a sign in form to a page using routing and button click.But i want it to hide than sign in form when we click that button again.

Comment: You're answer is really useful.you solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Switch,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

function SignIn() {
  return "hello";
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    current: ""
  };

  toggle = () => {
   
    this.setState({ current: this.state.current==''?"SignIn":"" })
      
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          {this.state.current == "SignIn" ? (
            <Redirect to="/SignIn" />
          ) : (
            <Redirect to="" />
          )}
          <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.toggle}>
            Sign In
          </button>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/SignIn" component={SignIn} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```